# Mapping issue while trying to send data to view

Tags: swift

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

using firebase database to save contact information and handle it
this is its model

Model

```
struct Contact {
var email: String!
var username: String!
var profileimage: String?
var userid: String!

init(email: String , username: String, profileimage: String, userid: String) {
    self.email = email
    self.username = username
    self.profileimage = profileimage
    self.userid = userid
}
}
```

Getting error while trying to change label outlet name

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatMessagesController") as! ChatMessagesController
    newViewController.user = user
    newViewController.navBarLabel.text = user.username

    self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Contact is decleared in the second view

```
class ChatMessagesController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

var user: Contact?
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlets are nil until vc loads so force that

```
newViewController.loadViewIfNeeded() 
newViewController.navBarLabel.text = user.username
```

also this `var username: String!` may be a cause also , so make sure it's not `nil`

Comment: thanks my friend i always had this issue while adding data didn't know why until now always learning somthing new thanks again.